# Extended attributes with rsync MacOS + nfs mounting

Tags: mac, mount, rsync

I'm using `rsync -avpX src tgt` to synchronize files from an HFS+ volume to a remote target on ZFS running Solaris 11.3. I'm using the latest rsync (3.1.3) from homebrew on macOS 10.14.2.

If `src` contains files that have colour tags in Finder, the extended attributes successfully copy over to `tgt`; I know this works because if I `rsync` in the reverse direction into an empty directory and I launch Finder, I can see the file tag colours. However, if I mount the remote file system with NFS or samba, the files do not have their colours. I assume the issue is that Finder isn't using or can't see the extended attributes (mdls yields nothing on the mount). Meanwhile, I can add colours from Finder to the remote mount, but the extended attributes get stored in a dot-file.

What I would like is for colours to remain synced on both. I assume what I need is a way to get rsync (or another tool) to write the extended attributes as dot-files during syncing or have Finder somehow read the extended attributes on my remote mount. Any hints/suggestions?